# What is the alternative for adjustsFontForContentSizeCategory iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

This Property work in only **iOS 10+ OS** what is alternative solution for replace property .

[Apple documentation for Objective C](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicontentsizecategoryadjusting/1771731-adjustsfontforcontentsizecategor?language=objc)

```
  @property(nonatomic) BOOL adjustsFontForContentSizeCategory;
```

[Apple documentation for Swift](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicontentsizecategoryadjusting/1771731-adjustsfontforcontentsizecategor)

```
var adjustsFontForContentSizeCategory: Bool { get set }
```

This property is not working in lower version when we open in lower version app is crash.

Answer (score 3):

In lower versions there is no defined property and you will have to handle it programatically, you will have to listen to system notification for the font change - `UIContentSizeCategoryDidChangeNotification`

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
      selector:@selector(didChangePreferredContentSize:)
          name:UIContentSizeCategoryDidChangeNotification
        object:nil];
```

Swift version

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: 
#selector(self.didChangePreferredContentSize), name: 
UIContentSizeCategoryDidChangeNotification, object: nil)
```

And you can then handle your requirement in the selector method - didChangePreferredContentSize.

Best practise guideline - Once you are leaving your view controller, do remember to remove observer.

Comment: @kapsym pleasure .

Answer (score 2):

In Swift 3, in iOS versions prior to 10, in order to have the font update when the user changed their preferred font size, we'd have to do something like:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var dynamicTextLabel: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        dynamicTextLabel.font = .preferredFont(forTextStyle: .body)

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: .UIContentSizeCategoryDidChange, object: nil, queue: .main) { [weak self] notification in
            self?.dynamicTextLabel.font = .preferredFont(forTextStyle: .body)
        }
    }

    deinit {
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: .UIContentSizeCategoryDidChange, object: nil)
    }
}
```